# Magento 2 Installation Database

Tags: database, installation, web-setup-wizard

I am trying to install Magento but when I get to the add database to the setup wizard I only get errors like these:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   No such host is known.

Here's my database adress on azure:

```
sqlsrv:server = tcp:construbee.database.windows.net,1433
```

I can acess the database trough a php code on another server, but on magento It is not working. Am I typing something wrong?